# What is this "db2 Password" prompt in MS Access 2010's Code Builder

Tags: ms-access

Can anyone tell me what this prompt means? I really know nothing about Access nor have much experience with VBA. My goal is to view the VBA code from an Access forms.

1. I open the .accdb file.
2. I open the Form Designer
3. I go to the **Design** ribbon, and click **View Code**
4. Visual Studio opens up and I get the following "db2 password" prompt:

Does this have anything to do with IBM's DB2 product? or is it just a misleading prompt?

Does this prompt mean that the developer has password protected the source code, but not the .accdb file itself?

[image: View code button]

[image: db2 password prompt]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access a VBA code project which is password protected. Nothing to do with IBM. They've just named their project `db2`

If you right click on a project > Properties you get this dialog. Someone has filled it out.[image]

Comment: Obviously you need to request the password from the original Developer, but as db2 is not a very sensible name for a database I would bet that the password is also "db2" (or "password").

Comment: Thanks Brad, that was exactly it. Except you need the password to view the project properties. The original developer was not available to ask for the password, but I was able to remove it using the method described at http://rohandatar.blogspot.com/2010/05/decoding-excel-vba-password.html